# Line Chart xAxis label with multiple colour using (iOS-charts) and LineChartData setValueTextColor

Tags: ios, swift, linechart, ios-charts

Here i'm using iOS-charts to implement line chart. I'm stuck with using multiple colours for xAxis labels and value at each data point.

https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

For xAxis i need NSAttributedString with two different colours, this is the code is used. Unable to figure it out how to do this.

```
    xChart.drawLabelsEnabled = true
    xChart.labelCount = 20
    xChart.labelFont = SomeFont
    xChart.labelTextColor = UIColor.white        
    xChart.labelPosition = .bottom
    xChart.labelHeight = 52.0
    xChart.granularityEnabled = true
    xChart.granularity = 1
    xChart.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: self.weeks)
```

similarly for valueTextColor at each data-point

```
    let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
    self.lineChart.data = lineChartData

    // Enables Text above Circle - Color and Font
    lineChartData.setDrawValues(true)
    lineChartData.setValueTextColor(.white)        
    lineChartData.setValueFont(some font)
```

And used value formatter to be in `Int`

[image: This is what I want to implement the one with green circles with two different colors]

This is what I want to implement the one with green circles with two different colors

[image: This is what I got]

This is what I got

Can anyone provide a solution to this??

Answered by @CodeChanger has fixed one issue, looking forward for another one at bottom of the image `19 Jun`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirements there is one property in ChartDataSet named "**valueColors**".

Please check below code to change your value color based on custom condition you can change color of your value.

```
let chartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: label)
chartDataSet.valueColors = [UIColor(red: 0.192, green: 0.686, blue: 0.980, alpha: 1.00),
                                    UIColor(red: 0.212, green: 0.863, blue: 0.318, alpha: 1.00),
                                    UIColor(red: 0.996, green: 0.867, blue: 0.275, alpha: 1.00),
                                    UIColor(red: 0.980, green: 0.090, blue: 0.157, alpha: 1.00)]
```

By This you can change your color of your value text.

Comment: that fixes valueColors, my bad that I missed this small fix. There is another one on bottom, I guess im missing something here and might be a small fix

Comment: Glad that its helps. Can you please accept this answer so other user can find it helpful?